# Issue regarding saving the images using kinetic js

Tags: html, kineticjs

After loading the image on to the stage and if am trying to save the image using the code

```
stage.toDataURL({
                callback: function(dataUrl) {
                window.open(dataUrl);
                },
                mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
                quality: 0.5
            });
```

I am getting an security script error in kinetic.js(i am using kinetic-v4.0.0.js)

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
return this.element.toDataURL();
```

Please help me out in this situation.

Comment: From the kineticjs site: "Note: The toDataURL() method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown."

Comment: then if we are loading the image from our local machine using file browse then what happens.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what it is KineticJS or not, the same origin policy applies to everywhere unless it is clearly stated; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

As you see in the document and tutorial, you cannot use other domains' source to make your domain png or jpeg. This also applies to toImage method

Document: http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Stage.php#toDataURL

Tutorial: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/

So, to go around this issue, you need to download other source image to your website, then use it under your domain. However, copyright must be checked as you know.